# How to use the argument of a function in a high order function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm sorry if the title was misleading but I'm not even sure what is my question. I have the following exercise:

We call x a fix point of a function f if f x==x (i.e. f maps x to itself). Write a function fixpoint which accepts a function f :: Integer -> Integer and returns the smallest non-negative integer x which is a fix
point of f.

So far all I could think off was:

```
fixpoint :: (a -> a) -> a

fixpoint f = min [f x | x<-[0..n], f x == x ]
```

but it is obviously flawed as the n is out of nowhere.

I've tried other things too but they were obvious mistakes.

What is a possible solution to this exercise? I'm new to Haskell and I don't even know how to think about that problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are other ways to solve it, but expanding on your idea, you can use `[0..]` to create an infinite list, so you don't need the `n`. Then you can't take the `min` of an infinite list, because it will never complete, but since your list counts up, the smallest one will be the first one, so you can use `head`:

```hs
fixpoint f = head [f x | x <- [0..], f x == x]
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know infinite lists existed. I still get an error on f x == x tho:  "No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of `==' "

Comment: That's because of your type signature. You need to add the `Eq` type class in order to use `==`, like `(Eq a) => (a -> a) -> a`.

Comment: Now I get an error on the "0", "Could not deduce (Num a) arising from the literal `0' "

Comment: @Udar GHC suggests how to fix that problem.

Comment: Your problem specified to use `Integer`, so you should just say `fixpoint :: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer` and have done with it.

Comment: It works now, I couldn't understand what ghc was suggesting. Thank you!